# How to reduce CreateTable transaction when use Azure function binding?

Tags: binding, azure-functions, azure-storage

Currently, my project is using Azure function 2.x.
I'm binding TableStorage to CloudTable. Function is triggered by Eventhub message

However, there are many CreateTable transactions. See picture below:
[image]

This transaction seem happens for every function invoke.
Check the source of in Github, that call the method: CreateIfNotExists() when binding, so I guess it can be the root cause of this behavior above. It is strange, too much CreateTable transactions does not happen in Azure function 1.x

Is there anyway to reduce CreateTable transaction?
May I need to use custom binding?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the code? If privacy is involved, just give the structure of the code is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are many CreateTable transactions.

The reason why have so many CreateTable transactions is because the underlying code is trying to create.

> Is there anyway to reduce CreateTable transaction? May I need to use
> custom binding?

I am not sure what language you are using now, if you try to use C# IBinder, maybe you will still run the create step. You can create your own logic in the body of function, I think this can perfectly avoid this problem. Just try to get it instead of create it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using C#. I'm looking for the way to disable CreateIfNotExist() every function trigger.

Comment: @duy If so, I think you should not using binding.

Comment: @duy I try to find it for you, I should have done something similar before.

Comment: Actually, manual binding is the last choice. I really do not want to apply it.

Comment: @duy Check this api document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable?view=azure-dotnet There are all of the methods. Function table binding is based on this.

Comment: @duy `CloudTableClient.GetTableReference(<stringtablename>)`, then you can use above methods.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=csharp
Follow the link, we cannot binding CloudTableClient, so I guess we need to create client manually

Comment: @duy This is a simple code reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#create-a-table